# Trying to open a file dialog using the new IFileDialog and IFileOpenDialog interfaces in C# with minimal code

Tags: c#, interface, com-interop, openfiledialog

I'm trying to display a standard open file dialog that can select folders, using the IFileOpenDialog interface in C#, Visual Studio 2010.

I'm trying to use the minimal code, so I've only defined the methods I need in the interfaces:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// Disable warning CS0108: 'x' hides inherited member 'y'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
\#pragma warning disable 0108

namespace FolderDialog
{

internal static class IIDGuid
{
    internal const string IModalWindow = "b4db1657-70d7-485e-8e3e-6fcb5a5c1802";
    internal const string IFileDialog = "42f85136-db7e-439c-85f1-e4075d135fc8";
    internal const string IFileOpenDialog = "d57c7288-d4ad-4768-be02-9d969532d960";
}

internal static class CLSIDGuid
{
    internal const string FileOpenDialog = "DC1C5A9C-E88A-4dde-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7";
}

static class NativeMethods
{

    [Flags]
    internal enum FOS : uint
    {
        FOS_PICKFOLDERS = 0x00000020
    }

}

[ComImport(),
Guid(IIDGuid.IModalWindow),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IModalWindow
{

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime),
    PreserveSig]
    int Show([In] IntPtr parent);
}

[ComImport(),
Guid(IIDGuid.IFileDialog),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IFileDialog : IModalWindow
{
    // Defined on IModalWindow - repeated here due to requirements of COM interop layer
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime),
    PreserveSig]
    int Show([In] IntPtr parent);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    void SetOptions([In] NativeMethods.FOS fos);
}

[ComImport(),
Guid(IIDGuid.IFileOpenDialog),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IFileOpenDialog : IFileDialog
{
    // Defined on IModalWindow - repeated here due to requirements of COM interop layer
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime),
    PreserveSig]
    int Show([In] IntPtr parent);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    void SetOptions([In] NativeMethods.FOS fos);
}


// ---------------------------------------------------
// .NET classes representing runtime callable wrappers
[ComImport,
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FCanCreate),
Guid(CLSIDGuid.FileOpenDialog)]
internal class FileOpenDialogRCW
{
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// Coclass interfaces - designed to "look like" the object 
// in the API, so that the 'new' operator can be used in a 
// straightforward way. Behind the scenes, the C# compiler
// morphs all 'new CoClass()' calls to 'new CoClassWrapper()'
[ComImport,
Guid(IIDGuid.IFileOpenDialog),
CoClass(typeof(FileOpenDialogRCW))]
internal interface NativeFileOpenDialog : IFileOpenDialog
{
}
```

}

If I only call

```
        IFileDialog dialog = null;
        try
        {
            dialog = new NativeFileOpenDialog();
            dialog.Show(IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dialog != null)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(dialog);
        }
```

it works fine and it opens the File Dialog without any errors.

If I try:

```
        IFileDialog dialog = null;
        try
        {
            dialog = new NativeFileOpenDialog();
            dialog.SetOptions(NativeMethods.FOS.FOS_PICKFOLDERS);
            dialog.Show(IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dialog != null)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(dialog);
        }
```

so If I add a call to the SetOptions method before the Show method call, I get an exception: *"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."*

I get this trying to run on .Net 2.0 or even 4.0.

What is the error here? Why does just calling the Show method work, but if I try another method before it fails?

Comment: Why are you using the native method instead of the managed version?

Comment: I want to be able to open folders, not files, the managed version can only open files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a class that opens a Vista-style folder picker using the .Net private `IFileDialog` interface, without directly using interop in the code (.Net takes care of that for you). It falls back to the pre-Vista dialog if not in a high enough Windows version. Should work in Windows 7, 8, 9, 10 and higher (theoretically).

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Ris.Shuriken {
    /// <summary>
    /// Present the Windows Vista-style open file dialog to select a folder. Fall back for older Windows Versions
    /// </summary>
    public class FolderSelectDialog {
        private string _initialDirectory;
        private string _title;
        private string _fileName = "";

        public string InitialDirectory {
            get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_initialDirectory) ? Environment.CurrentDirectory : _initialDirectory; }
            set { _initialDirectory = value; }
        }
        public string Title {
            get { return _title ?? "Select a folder"; }
            set { _title = value; }
        }
        public string FileName { get { return _fileName; } }

        public bool Show() { return Show(IntPtr.Zero); }

        /// <param name="hWndOwner">Handle of the control or window to be the parent of the file dialog</param>
        /// <returns>true if the user clicks OK</returns>
        public bool Show(IntPtr hWndOwner) {
            var result = Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6
                ? VistaDialog.Show(hWndOwner, InitialDirectory, Title)
                : ShowXpDialog(hWndOwner, InitialDirectory, Title);
            _fileName = result.FileName;
            return result.Result;
        }

        private struct ShowDialogResult {
            public bool Result { get; set; }
            public string FileName { get; set; }
        }

        private static ShowDialogResult ShowXpDialog(IntPtr ownerHandle, string initialDirectory, string title) {
            var folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog {
                Description = title,
                SelectedPath = initialDirectory,
                ShowNewFolderButton = false
            };
            var dialogResult = new ShowDialogResult();
            if (folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog(new WindowWrapper(ownerHandle)) == DialogResult.OK) {
                dialogResult.Result = true;
                dialogResult.FileName = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
            }
            return dialogResult;
        }

        private static class VistaDialog {
            private const string c_foldersFilter = "Folders|\n";

            private const BindingFlags c_flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            private readonly static Assembly s_windowsFormsAssembly = typeof(FileDialog).Assembly;
            private readonly static Type s_iFileDialogType = s_windowsFormsAssembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.FileDialogNative+IFileDialog");
            private readonly static MethodInfo s_createVistaDialogMethodInfo = typeof(OpenFileDialog).GetMethod("CreateVistaDialog", c_flags);
            private readonly static MethodInfo s_onBeforeVistaDialogMethodInfo = typeof(OpenFileDialog).GetMethod("OnBeforeVistaDialog", c_flags);
            private readonly static MethodInfo s_getOptionsMethodInfo = typeof(FileDialog).GetMethod("GetOptions", c_flags);
            private readonly static MethodInfo s_setOptionsMethodInfo = s_iFileDialogType.GetMethod("SetOptions", c_flags);
            private readonly static uint s_fosPickFoldersBitFlag = (uint) s_windowsFormsAssembly
                .GetType("System.Windows.Forms.FileDialogNative+FOS")
                .GetField("FOS_PICKFOLDERS")
                .GetValue(null);
            private readonly static ConstructorInfo s_vistaDialogEventsConstructorInfo = s_windowsFormsAssembly
                .GetType("System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog+VistaDialogEvents")
                .GetConstructor(c_flags, null, new[] { typeof(FileDialog) }, null);
            private readonly static MethodInfo s_adviseMethodInfo = s_iFileDialogType.GetMethod("Advise");
            private readonly static MethodInfo s_unAdviseMethodInfo = s_iFileDialogType.GetMethod("Unadvise");
            private readonly static MethodInfo s_showMethodInfo = s_iFileDialogType.GetMethod("Show");

            public static ShowDialogResult Show(IntPtr ownerHandle, string initialDirectory, string title) {
                var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog {
                    AddExtension = false,
                    CheckFileExists = false,
                    DereferenceLinks = true,
                    Filter = c_foldersFilter,
                    InitialDirectory = initialDirectory,
                    Multiselect = false,
                    Title = title
                };

                var iFileDialog = s_createVistaDialogMethodInfo.Invoke(openFileDialog, new object[] { });
                s_onBeforeVistaDialogMethodInfo.Invoke(openFileDialog, new[] { iFileDialog });
                s_setOptionsMethodInfo.Invoke(iFileDialog, new object[] { (uint) s_getOptionsMethodInfo.Invoke(openFileDialog, new object[] { }) | s_fosPickFoldersBitFlag });
                var adviseParametersWithOutputConnectionToken = new[] { s_vistaDialogEventsConstructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] { openFileDialog }), 0U };
                s_adviseMethodInfo.Invoke(iFileDialog, adviseParametersWithOutputConnectionToken);

                try {
                    int retVal = (int) s_showMethodInfo.Invoke(iFileDialog, new object[] { ownerHandle });
                    return new ShowDialogResult {
                        Result = retVal == 0,
                        FileName = openFileDialog.FileName
                    };
                }
                finally {
                    s_unAdviseMethodInfo.Invoke(iFileDialog, new[] { adviseParametersWithOutputConnectionToken[1] });
                }
            }
        }

        // Wrap an IWin32Window around an IntPtr
        private class WindowWrapper : IWin32Window {
            private readonly IntPtr _handle;
            public WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle) { _handle = handle; }
            public IntPtr Handle { get { return _handle; } }
        }
    }
}
```

I developed this as a cleaned up version of [.NET Win 7-style folder select dialog](http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=136) by Bill Seddon of [lyquidity.com](http://lyquidity.com) (I have no affiliation). I wrote my own because his solution requires an additional Reflection class that isn't needed for this focused purpose, uses exception-based flow control, doesn't cache the results of its reflection calls. Note that the nested static `VistaDialog` class is so that its static reflection variables don't try to get populated if the `Show` method is never called.

It is used like so in a Windows Form:

```
var dialog = new FolderSelectDialog {
    InitialDirectory = musicFolderTextBox.Text
    Title = "Select a folder to import music from"
};
if (dialog.Show(Handle)) {
    musicFolderTextBox.Text = dialog.FileName;
}
```

You can of course play around with its options and what properties it exposes. For example, it allows multiselect in the Vista-style dialog.

As alluded to in his answer in this thread, [Simon Mourier's answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15386992/57611) shows how to do the job using interop directly. Unfortunately, I hadn't found that yet when I worked up my solution. Name your poison!

Comment: Is there any way (eg some flag) to enable the user to choose a Folder OR File at the same time? Alternatively: Is there any way to show also the files inside each folder when user browse to select a folder?

Comment: @S.Serpooshan just ask a new question!

Answer (score 5):

The [Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) can help. After you download it, look at "\Windows API Code Pack 1.1\source\WindowsAPICodePack\Shell\CommonFileDialogs\CommonFileDialog.cs" to see how it uses IFileDialogCustomize from COM.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The above link to the API Code Pack is broken, but see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081665/windows-api-code-pack-where-is-it).

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but you can find an example of IFileDialog interfaces in C# here on SO in my answer: [Show detailed Folder Browser from a PropertyGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368771/show-detailed-folder-browser-from-a-propertygrid) and another variation that allows the selection of non file system folders (like My Computer/This PC) here: [C# How to allow selection of My Computer with folderBrowserDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639091/c-sharp-folderbrowserdialog-is-not-showing-ok-button-on-selecting-my-computer)

Comment: See my [new answer referencing yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33835934/57611). I think this answer would be vastly improved if you just copied and pasted your entire answer that you linked.

Comment: @ErikE - well, thanks for pinging me, but I now have two related answers so I'm kinda torn between the variations :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply trying to open a folder browser dialog, you may be over-complicating the issue. Use the [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) class instead.

Comment: The problem with `FolderBrowserDialog` is that it doesn't let you type in a textbox (or copy or paste) and it doesn't show favorites and sometimes certain network locations. It can be really hard to work with. It also doesn't allow multi-select.