# What is a plus sign in reflection get type?

Tags: system.reflection

Trying to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33835934/57883) old code working as I don't remember even why we used it instead of just using the built-ins. What is the plus sign in get type supposed to do? I don't see any sign of special types when I reflect on a current version of `System.Windows.Forms`

- "System.Windows.Forms.FileDialogNative+IFileDialog"
- "System.Windows.Forms.FileDialogNative+FOS"
- "System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog+VistaDialogEvents"